# Numpy bitwise xor on signed int

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading in some binary data that is in offset binary format.  The signed integers in `numpy` are in twos compliment so the values are incorrect.  To fix the data I need to flip the most significant bit.  However, I am getting some unexpected results from the bitwise xor and not entirely sure what is going on.

Example:

```
data = np.array([1, 7, -1, -8], dtype='i1')
mask = 0b10000000

def print_bin(data, out):
    for d, o in zip(data, out):
        bin_data =np.binary_repr(d, d.dtype.itemsize*8)
        bin_out = np.binary_repr(o, o.dtype.itemsize*8)
        print(f'{bin_data} to {bin_out}')
        
print_bin(data, data ^ mask)
```

Output:

```
00000001 to 0000000010000001
00000111 to 0000000010000111
11111111 to 1111111101111111
11111000 to 1111111101111000
```

It seems `numpy` is maybe doing some kind of casting before the xor since the output is 16-bit integer.  If I use the functional form `np.bitwise_xor` instead of `^` I get the same results.  Interestingly if I do the xor with `-mask` the values come out correct.  Or if I specify the dtype in the functional form.

```
print_bin(data, np.bitwise_xor(data, mask, dtype='i1'))
print_bin(data, data ^ -mask)
```

Output:

```
00000001 to 10000001
00000111 to 10000111
11111111 to 01111111
11111000 to 01111000
```

Can anyone explain exactly what is happening in the first case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mask = 0b10000000` is an unsigned integer representation:

```
>>> mask
... 128
```

This would need 16 bits to represent as a signed integer, hence numpy casts all the ints to 16 bits to accommodate this operation. You are looking for the signed integer that has the binary representation `'10000000'`. This corresponds to the integer `-128`.

So `mask = -128` should solve your problem! This is also why negating the mask works (`-mask = -128 = '10000000' as a signed int`.

Casting the mask to a int8 numpy integer will also do the trick:

```
>>> np.array(0b10000000, dtype='i1')
... array(-128, dtype=int8)
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I was assuming numpy should just know that I wanted the mask in the binary representation I set.  However, I suppose since Python doesn't really have unsigned types there is no way for numpy to know exactly what I meant.   I was a little surprised that if I define the mask as `array(128, dtype='u1')` it still gets it wrong.  I would think that numpy would be smart enough to see the bit widths are the same and use `view` to perform the bitwise operations.

Comment: Yeah I agree it is a little surprising. I suppose it would have to do with some definition of how to deal with operations that consist of both unsigned and signed ints. You could just take the bit value and cast it either to unsigned or signed (but there might be ambiguities on which way to go here). Or you convert the signed int to the unsigned representation (which would involve using more bits)... Numpy apparently chose the later or these two options. Would be interesting to know if this is a standard way of dealing with the problem